# Remove garbage from database

Tags: mysql

My database contains two field "name" and "generic_name" with a lot of data. but it has some information that i don't need. example :

```
       name
    ----------         
item    

                      J  E    4                               
                              Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +   


     generic_name
  -----------------
item    

                      J  E    4                               
                              Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +
```

I am not expecting the following string in any field :

```
                "J  E    4                                
                              Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +   "
```

I am not good with sql queries. Please suggest how can i remove the garbage string from all the cells.

here is the query i tried :

```
  DELETE FROM `master_med` WHERE `Sl_No` IN ( SELECT Sl_No from `master_med` where `MEDICINE_NAME`=' J  E    4                                                                    Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +                       ')
```

Getting error : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'master_med' for update in FROM clause
Run SQL query/queries on database medinfo: Documentation

Comment: Are you expecting just "item" in both field?

Comment: thats very unclear what you are asking, please format your table again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear, what you're asking. 
This  is probably the best answer i can give you without more infos. 
Remember it's mostly bad approach to identify rows on comparing long strings. 
The best action would be to create md5 of this string and then find it in row and then delete it.

```
$string_hash = md5('string i dont want to');
DELETE FROM table WHERE MD5(item) = $string_hash
```

OR alternatively (not very good approach)

```
DELETE FROM `master_med` WHERE `Sl_No` IN (
    SELECT Sl_No FROM
    (
        SELECT Sl_No from `master_med` where TRIM(MEDICINE_NAME)=TRIM('JE    4                                                                    Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +                       ')
    ) AS todelete
 )
```

Comment: i want to delete the unnecessary string J  E    4                                
                                  Share           Facebook           Stumbleupon         Twitter           Google+              Pinterest           Linkedin        +    from all the cells

Comment: getting error using your 2nd option. You can't specify target table 'master_med' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Update your answer and post your sql

Comment: getting this error now : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: it's executing with no error but not updating by deleting the unexpected string

Comment: I just updated my answer though it would be faster and more efficient if you go with my first solution